# Is it possible to accomplish heavy traffic Chat with WCF?

Tags: .net, wcf, performance

I want to build a site with support chat with thousands of users which need to communicate with each other.

**Assuming** I have excellent hardware , is it possible and smart to do the communication stuff via WCF?

Comment: How many messages per second do you consider "heavy traffic"?

Comment: Maybe you could beef up your question with more information about how many messages/sec, message size etc?

Comment: are you trying to do this over the internet or within an intranet? When you say 1000's of users do you mean 1000's of concurrent messages or 1000's of users "online" at the moment? What is the real requirement over message latency (how long between message send and message receive is acceptable)? You have been amazingly non specific about what you are actually trying to achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You can make a chat server/client with WCF but not for heavy traffic.](http://tomasz.janczuk.org/2009/08/performance-of-http-polling-duplex.html)

The article says:

"The data indicates a single server can support 2000 simultaneous chat rooms with 2 participants each and a 15 second delay between publications with a 25ms mean latency (0 ms median latency), which should satisfy latency requirements of most UI driven scenarios. At the same time, the data shows that the latency gets out of hand with 800 chatrooms with 3 participants each and 15 second delay between publications."

I think you should basically use XMPP instead.

Clarification: Unlike what a "WCF expert" commenter below claimed, polling duplex is the common method for chatting server as it is the closest thing to BOSH, which is very popular http based protocol for chatting communication. BTW, I am not an expert in this area but had several weeks to build a chat server with XMPP over BOSH. First we tried to build the server with WCF but went with the different route because of what real experts recommended.

Comment: Do you have any reasons or facts why it won't work for heavy traffic?

Comment: Sorry. it was wrong post and corrected. Read the conclusion part. Basically performance does not match with XMPP.

Comment: this is complete nonsense until we have some details of what the "chat" application is about - polling duplex is a very specific and very odd WCF binding and you cannot take that as a benchmark hence the down vote

Comment: @Richard Blewett, I am just wondering how you would implement "chat" application with WCF other than polling duplex then. Enlighten me please.

Comment: PollDuplex *might* be necessary if you are using Silverlight over the Internet - but as the OP hasn't specified that restriction netPeerTcp or netTcp might well work as well

Comment: I am giving you one more chance before tagging you "complete nonsense". 1. What does PollDuplex have to do with Silverlight? 2. Chatting application over tcp sounds great, but how would you handle clients that does not afford to have long-lived tcp? I am giving you a hint: Why do you think XMPP over BOSH is so popular?

Answer (score 1):

Nothing stopping you. You'll need to implement you own pub/sub on top of WCF.